# How to add HashMap to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Can someone please tell me why the code below overwrites every element in the ArrayList with the most recent entry into the ArrayList?  Or how to correctly add new elements of hashmaps to my ArrayList?

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> prodArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

HashMap<String, String> prodHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

public void addProd(View ap)
{
    // test arraylist of hashmaps
    prodHashMap.put("prod", tvProd.getText().toString());

    prodArrayList.add(prodHashMap);

    tvProd.setText("");

    // check data ///

    Log.e("myLog","Data prodArrayList in ADD Method Size = "+prodArrayList.size());

    for(int i=0; i< prodArrayList.size();i++)
    {
         Log.e("myLog","Data prodArrayList in ADD Method = "+prodArrayList.get(i).toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**problem:**

```
prodHashMap.put("prod", tvProd.getText().toString());
```

You are using the same key each time you are adding an element to the the arraylist with the same reference to the `HashMap` thus changing its values.

**Solution:**

create a new instance of `HashMap` each time you want to add it to the `ArrayList` to avoid changing its values upon calling `addProd`

```
public void addProd(View ap)
{
    // test arraylist of hashmaps
    HashMap<String, String> prodHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    prodHashMap.put("prod", tvProd.getText().toString());

    prodArrayList.add(prodHashMap);

    tvProd.setText("");

    // check data ///

    Log.e("myLog","Data prodArrayList in ADD Method Size = "+prodArrayList.size());

    for(int i=0; i< prodArrayList.size();i++)
    {
         Log.e("myLog","Data prodArrayList in ADD Method = "+prodArrayList.get(i).toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. I get it now.  Thank you for the explanation.  I will mark as correct in ten min.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is for adding multiple maps to List

```
Map<String,Object> map1=new HashMap<>();
map1.  // add required items

Map<String,Object> map2=new HashMap<>();
map2.  // add required items

Map<String,Object> map3=new HashMap<>();
map3.  // add required items

List<String,Object> list=new ArrayList<>();

list.add(map1);

list.add(map2);

list.add(map3);
```

Comment: use 4 spaces at the beginning of any line of code to format your code better